# ibex - System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: 'format-date()' is an unknown XSLT-Function

Tags: c#, xslt

I'm getting the following error when using ibex library:

> System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: 'format-date()' is an unknown XSLT-Function.

This is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <!-- ... -->
    <fo:block-container position="absolute" top="7*0.125in" left="0in" height="1*0.125in" line-height="0.125in" font-family="Courier" font-size="10pt">
        <fo:block>Testof  
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date(//Testobject/Date, '[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
    <!-- ... -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestions why I am getting this error when transforming to PDF with ibex (version 4.8.8.6)?

I must use this XSLT file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of Ibex states "The actual execution of the XSLT translation can be done either by Ibex, which uses the .NET framework XSL translation objects [I interpret this to mean the Microsoft XSLT processor], or externally to Ibex using any XSLT engine."

It also says "The Ibex command line program will create a PDF file from either (a) an FO file or (b) an XML file with an XSLT stylesheet."

So you need to:

1. Run the XSLT transformation using an XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon or XmlPrime (from a .NET program or from the command line. If you're using the command line, then in the case of Saxon you may be better off using the Java version rather than the .NET version).
2. Run Ibex against the XSL-FO file output by step 1.

Comment: Thanks, I am already using Saxon for transformation to FO-File and then doing the PDF transformation.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use XSLT 2.0 with an XSLT 1.0 processor (Microsoft's various XSLT processors only support XSLT 1.0). To use XSLT 2.0 only features like `format-date` you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 (available in a [.NET version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.7/SaxonHE9-7-0-18N-setup.exe/download) at https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.7/) or [XmlPrime](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/download.htm) or AltovaXML (https://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html as an editor or as a processor https://www.altova.com/raptorxml.html). Saxon 9 is also part of various XML IDEs like [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/), [oXygen](https://www.oxygenxml.com/) or [Liquid Studio](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-studio).

Comment: Thanks. I thought ibex is using XSLT 2.0, but it seems it doesn't. Can I use Saxon HE to transform XML to PDF?